# Looking for a tutorial - ProGuard for Android MAVEN project

Tags: android, maven, proguard

Trying to integrate ProGuard in my android-maven project release phase. It seam that I'm missing something, but I can figure out what.

I tried the suggested example on the official [site](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ProGuard) but when I run maven with profile that contains the phase with proguard, there is no effect... I can't even see the proguard output (I tried to run maven with -X parameter also).

So my question is is there a nice and full tutorial, that will explain how to setup proguard in projects pom from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the tutorial [Proguard for Android with Maven without shooting yourself in the foot](http://www.simpligility.com/2010/12/proguard-for-android-with-maven-without-shooting-yourself-in-the-foot/).

Comment: The links in that tutorial all return error 404

Answer (score 0):

Look here 
https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/morseflash/morseflash-app

There is a Proguard config with a pom file.

Comment: This link does not work